# Eclipse startup issues

Tags: eclipse

All of a sudden, Eclipse that used to work perfectly won't launch anymore. Here is the log:

```
!SESSION 2012-11-13 11:10:21.718 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20060921-0945
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=ko_KR
Framework arguments:  -vm C:\j2sdk1.4.2_19\bin\javaw.exe
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -vm C:\j2sdk1.4.2_19\bin\javaw.exe

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.common 4 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.281
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent.ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:291)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.312
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent.ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.4,CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:291)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.328
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent.ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:291)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.328
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.2.0.v20060603.jar/ was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.328
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.2.2.R32x_v20070111.jar/ was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.328
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.2.0.v20060603.jar/ was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.343
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/com.ibm.etools.emf.event_3.0.0.v20060918_M.jar [4] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.etools.emf.event 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore_[2.2.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.etools.emf.event 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.etools.emf.event 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[2.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/com.jcraft.jsch_0.1.28.jar [7] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.jcraft.jsch 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.4
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.apache.ant_1.6.5/ [8] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.ant 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.2
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.apache.axis_1.3.0.v200608161946/ [9] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.axis 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.ant_[1.6.5,1.7.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.axis 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.commons.httpclient_[3.0.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.apache.lucene_1.4.103.v20060601/ [13] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.3
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.apache.wsil4j_1.0.0.v200608161946/ [14] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.wsil4j 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.uddi4j_[2.0.4,2.1.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.wsil4j 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.axis_[1.3.0,1.4.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.ant.core_3.1.100.v20060531.jar [16] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.core 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.variables_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.core 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.2.1.r321_v20060828.jar [17] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.views_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.editors_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.ant_1.6.5.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ant.core_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.filesystem_[1.0.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.625
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.filebuffers_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.variables_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.externaltools_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.console_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.core_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.expressions_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.icu.text_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.compare_3.2.1.M20060711.jar [18] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.views_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.icu.util_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.icu.text_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.core.boot_3.1.100.v20060603.jar [19] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.boot 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.core.commands_3.2.0.I20060605-1400.jar [20] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.commands 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-13 11:10:23.640
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.2.0.v20060603.jar [21] was not resolved.
```

From the line Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3, my understanding is that it has some sort of version conflict with J2SE, but the log correctly shows my current java version so I am not sure what the issue is at all.

Assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems to happen for every update to the JVM.  Just had the same issue with an eclipse instance I need to run under 1.7, but I had 1.9 installed and it failed. The accepted answer gave me what I needed to get past this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an **old** version of Eclipse with a **new** JRE.  I won't guess as to how/why `c:\j2sdk1.4.2_19` contains a Java 7 JRE, but either update your Eclipse, or go back to using an actual 1.4 JRE.

Comment: That's strange, because the folder contains verison 1.4.2, not 1.7.0. I'm not sure why it's doing this. I'll investigate into this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that was fixed by modifying **PATH** in a **startAnOldEclipse.bat** file so that the PATH pointed to a jre bin directory for a version of the jre required by that version of Eclipse. This PATH also contains just enough Windows stuff too e.g.,

```
set PATH=<tool suite stuff>;c:\j2sdk1.4.2_19\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
```

I'd guess that your eclipse stopped working because a new JRE was installed and the PATH was modified to point to the new JRE.

In my case, the 'tool suite stuff' was a gcc cross-compiler that was packaged with an old eclipse.

**Another way to specify a specific JRE**:
[This](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F) says: "The most recommended way to specify a JVM for Eclipse to run in is to put startup configuration into the eclipse.ini"

Comment: This doesn't affect the vm used by the launcher, which is what is failing here. You can specify on the command line in a batch file or shortcut, however

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downloading the OLD version of the JDK 1.4, configuring the PATH of local variables, and adding the new path to `C:\j2sdk1.4.2_19\bin`. This works after relaunching eclipse.