# Eclipse doesn't open

Tags: java, eclipse

When I start eclipse it shows: An error has occurred. See the log file.
The log file contains this:

```
!SESSION 2020-02-12 19:35:02.241 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
java.version=13.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
```

org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-02-12 19:35:02.931
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System Bundle could not be resolved: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 13 more
```

This is an eclipse version with a plugin called KyBDele

Comment: try editing the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert -clean as the first line https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849024/why-is-eclipse-3-2-throwing-an-error-on-startup

Comment: This appears to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354705/eclipse-startup-issues

Comment: Eclipse 4.3 is far too old to run with Java 13. Use the current Eclipse 2019-12 or try Java 8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse startup issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354705/eclipse-startup-issues)